# Why isn't this use of inject working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why isn't this use of [inject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001494) working?

Ruby:

```
p "STARTING"
notes = notes.find_all{|note| note.date_occurred == date}
p notes.class
p notes.inject{|sum, note| sum + note.time_spent }
```

Output:

```
"STARTING"
Array
#<Note id: 82, time_spent: 5, created_at: "2011-08-29 00:32:26", updated_at: "2011-08-29 00:32:31", date_occurred: "2011-08-29">
```

I'm using Rails 3.0.1 and Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: fwiw: notes.where(:date_occurred => date).sum(:time_spent) would be much more efficient if you just want the total of this column.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Quick question, is the efficiency gain in both the where and sum methods?

Comment: Yes. My example would do most of the work inside the database; yours is going over the entire collection at least twice and possibly de-serializing AR objects that aren't cached etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the initial value for the "memo" to `inject`, like:

```
notes.inject(0) {|sum, note| sum + note.time_spent }
```